# How to make raw data from cross-tab frequency table in Python?

Tags: python, database, frequency, raw-data, contingency

I have a cross-tab such as the following (the number of each cell represents frequency count; Var1 is a binary Gender variable; M=male; F=female):

```
          Group1     Group2      Group3
Var1=M     34          23          54
Var1=F     14          43          57
```

How can I recreate the "raw" data like the following?

```
Var1      Group-Type
 M           Group1
 F           Group3
 F           Group2
```

The total number of rows for the raw data should be the sum of all the frequencies above, or 225.

Comment: please add more details. what does the pivot table represent? are the values frequency counts? are the pivot table row indices `Var1=M` & `Var2=F` or `M` & `F`?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, more details added.